# When using Conducto for CI/CD will I have to create my own dockerfile?

Tags: python, c++, conducto

I'm looking to move my CI/CD onto Conducto. This will involve building c++ code, running static analysis on python and c++ code, as well as running tests for python and c++ code. While I understand that I can use pre-defined images from dockerhub I believe my setup will be more involved as I need to install dependencies for both python and c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Making the base container

I suggest using a dockerfile that creates your devenv and has none of your code.

For your Dockerfile, use

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y gcc
# Use 'RUN <command>' to add whatever other packages you need.
```

For your node's `image`, use `co.Image(dockerfile="path/to/Dockerfile")` and it will build your Dockerfile into an image and use it for all descendant nodes. The path is evaluated relative to the file containing this function call.

### Getting your code into the new container

Follow the advice in [Conducto Execution Environments](https://medium.com/conducto/execution-environment-5a66ff0a10bc#27d5).

**To copy local code**, use `co.Image(dockerfile="../Dockerfile", copy_dir=".")` to copy the contents of `.` (the directory your file lives in). Live Debug will work automatically, and to rebuild your images just click the "Rebuild" button in the app.

**To pull files from git** instead, substitute `copy_url` and `copy_branch` instead of `copy_dir`, and Conducto will `git pull` instead of copying the code from your local filesystem. To update your images, just git push your code and then click "Rebuild" and Conducto will grab it anew. If you want to run Live Debug (which you should, it's awesome), specify path_map as explained in "Mounting Local Code for Debugging" at the above link.